# How do I use the result from a 'Future' function in Flutter that I created in other parts of my app?

Tags: flutter

So here basically what I am trying to do is I am trying to get the data that is calculated from the 'Geolocator.distanceBetween()' function and use it in other parts of my app as shown in the code below with comments, can someone please help me?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:environcycle_prototype/ExtraUtility/CornerIcon.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class Belait extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BelaitState createState() => _BelaitState();
}

class _BelaitState extends State<Belait> {

  Position _currentUserPosition;
  double distanceInMeters1 = 0;

  Future getTheDistance1() async {
    _currentUserPosition = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);

   double distanceInMeters1 = await Geolocator.distanceBetween(
    4.7074,
    114.5423,
    _currentUserPosition.latitude,
    _currentUserPosition.longitude,
    ); //this basically calculates the distance in meters for me
    
//if i add a 'print(distanceInMeters1)' here it shows me that the distance calculator is working and gives me a value of 12536913.098192418 (which is correct),  but how do i use this data (12536913.098192418) which is a string of numbers in other parts of my app such as in the next comment on the bottom of my code 

    setState(() {
      return distanceInMeters1;
    });
    
}

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.green[50],
    body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(width: 20),
                  Text('Meters Away') //I want the value here right before the text 'meters away'
                ],
              ),
```

Comment: Have you tried a [future builder?](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately it didn't really work for me, do you have an example code of future builder that i can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a future builder like so:

```
Future<double> getTheDistance1() async {
  _currentUserPosition = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);

  double distanceInMeters1 = await Geolocator.distanceBetween(
    4.7074,
    114.5423,
    _currentUserPosition.latitude,
    _currentUserPosition.longitude,
  );
  return distanceInMeters1;
}


Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return FutureBuilder<double>(
  future: getTheDistance1(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.green[50],
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(width: 20),
                  if (snapshot.hasData)
                  Text('${snapshot.data!} Meters Away')
                ],
              ),
  });
```

Hopefully this code is enough to fix your problem

Comment: I just implemented this into my code and it worked like a charm! Thank you so much! I am quite new to flutter and FutureBuilder is kind of a new problem to me, thanks so much again >w<

Comment: Pardon me for asking another question, but if I were to have a second value (e.g. 'getTheDistance2()' can the future builder return that value too along with the first one? (assuming that i need to use both getTheDistance1() and getTheDistance2()'s value in two separate parts of my code

Comment: I guess it depends on the use, you could do one of two things, either nest future builders, so have a future builder and another future builder and then the UI, or use `Future.wait`, to do that, set the future to be `future: Future.wait([getTheDistance1(), getTheDistance2()]),` on the future builder, then `snapshot.data[0]` will be the first result and `snapshot.data[1]` the second result, of course you can have more than 2 futures this way

Comment: Wow, I see! Thanks a lot for your help! this helps so much you don't understand how much it means to me, I have been working on trying to get the output out of the future widget for 4 days straight day and night and trying everyday, Only yesterday i posted on StackOverflow and you helped me, thank you very much! .w.

Comment: Hey, I am super happy to have helped you! :)

Comment: Another short question if it's possible for you to answer, may i know how do i round the value off to the nearest int?

Comment: IIRC there are 3 rounding related methods you can use, the simplest one is `round()`, `return distanceInMeters1.round()` will round it to the nearest integer, there is also `.ceil()` and `.floor` which will round up and down respectively, so for example `0.9999` round will round to 1, ceil will also round to one and floor will round down to 0. Hope that's clear

Comment: That's the end to my string of questions, thank you a lot! Thanks for making my day better by knowing that this is not a problem to me anymore, have a great day! :)

Comment: glad to have helped you :)!